# Invariant Violation: "trackerApp" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, mobile

i struggle since a several days with the following error:

```
 **Invariant Violation: "trackerApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.**
```

i check everything, but nothing worked.

**Code in app.json**

```
{
  "name": "trackerApp",
  "displayName": "trackerApp"
}
```

**Code in index.js**

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
// import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
// import App from "./src/App.tsx";

// Register the service
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the cache

```
cd android
```

and then

```
./gradlew clean
```

Build again

If does not work, delete the node_modules folder and use `yarn install` or `npm install` to reinstall the packages again.

If still not working check in theses files if they all have the "trackerApp"

1 - **root/package.json** *(usually on line 2)*

```
{"name": "trackerApp"}
```

2 - **root/android/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'trackerApp'
```

3 - **root/android/app/src/debug/java/com/trackerApp/ReactNativeFlipper.java** *(on first line of code below the comments)*

```
package com.trackerApp;
```

4 - **root/android/app/src/main/java/com/trackerApp/ReactNativeFlipper.java**

> inside function ***initializeFlipper*** check if is ***com.trackerApp.ReactNativeFlipper***

```
Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.trackerApp.ReactNativeFlipper");
```